# LInephone source code not working with TCP for local SIP calls

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tcp, sip, linphone

I downloaded the source code of Linphone app from GitHub (https://github.com/onmyway133/linphone-iphone) and tried to run it on my iPhone. It is working fine with transport selected as UDP but when I select transport setting as TCP outgoing works fine but the app don't notify about any incoming call.
I also tried to track the network calls by installing Linphone for mac on my macbook but for TCP it not even start any session of network requests.

Any one faced such issue or is there any other way to achieve SIP calling in local network? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Any one who down voted this question also post the comment.. so that I can know what is wrong here..

Comment: Its working fine with UDP as well as TCP. iphone is no more supporting udp packets for voip and so linphone is not notify incoming call when udp transport selected. Try TCP and random port enable.

Comment: @kaushikparmar thanks for your reply. The application downloaded from app store works fine the way you mentioned here. But the source code I mentioned above is not working with TCP and random port enabled/disabled. Have you tried the source code of linphone? if there is any other link please share.

Comment: i am using source code that i cloned before 4 months. It working fine for me.

Comment: @kaushikparmar can you please share it with me? because I also tried to clone it from git link available on linphone.org but that has lots of missing files and library. And the code mentioned in the question is not working with TCP.

Comment: @kaushikparmar kindly send that code at sudhanshu@techlites.com

Comment: As you already know , linphone build ios code is greater than 1 gb. So brother i can not mail it.

Comment: Do one thing , clone latest code from git and checkout to old version. and build it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code at the URL mentioned in the question "https://github.com/onmyway133/linphone-iphone" is not latest one. I had to check out the latest version from git url mention at linphone.org and after trying it many times finally I got the complete code and also I had to do few changes to compile the latest source code successfully.
I faced this error while compiling the code on terminal:

> > Shell script 'Makefile' at path 'linphone-iphone/submodules/build-i386-apple-darwin/mssilk/sdk' was downloading corrupt SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip.
> >
> > Fix: System terminal was downloading only 600Kbs of file size (i.e. corrupt zipped file) from the URL [http://developer.skype.com/silk/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip](http://developer.skype.com/silk/SILK%5fSDK%5fSRC%5fv1.0.9.zip) due to which next command was not able to unzip it and was displaying file missing error. I changed the default URL to '[http://bkvoice.googlecode.com/files/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip](http://bkvoice.googlecode.com/files/SILK%5fSDK%5fSRC%5fv1.0.9.zip)' thus process was able to download the file that was actually 62.9MBs of size.

Hope it'll help someone.